# strips out all characters except: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, underscore and the forward slash from a String using Python

Tags: python, regex

Using regular expression strips out all characters except a-z, A-Z, 0-9, underscore and the forward slash from a String and All other characters are to get removed and replaced by an underscore. In the replaced version, no consecutive multiple underscores should exist.

For example,

input :- "Ab 4/5        (t) "
output:- "Ab_4/5_t_"

input :- "AB___cd@#   E"
output:- "AB_cd_E"

Comment: Your efforts so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` with a pattern that replaces one or more consecutive unwanted characters with an underscore:

```
import re
output = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9/]+', '_', s)
```

so that given `s = 'Ab 4/5 (t)'`, `output` becomes:

```
Ab_4/5_t_
```

and that given `s = 'AB___cd@# E'`, `output` becomes:

```
AB_cd_E
```

Comment: thanks sir, it's working